# SQL Server OpenQuery WHERE IN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert records into an existing table from another server using `OpenQuery`, I am not sure why this is not working, but I am getting this error

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ContractsLinkedServer" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed."

Here is the query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.People([PersonId], [HomeId], [ContractId])
    SELECT 
       [PersonId], [HomeId], [ContractId]
    FROM
       OPENQUERY(ContractsLinkedServer,'SELECT [PersonId], [HomeId], [ContractId] 
                                        FROM RSB.dbo.People
                                        WHERE ContractId IN (SELECT ContractId From Contracts ) ') a
```

Comment: Long shot but does the select work without the insert?

Comment: Why not get rid of the `WHERE IN` and just do 
 `FROM Contracts c inner join 
      OPENQUERY(ContractsLinkedServer,'SELECT [PersonId],[HomeId] ,[ContractId] FROM RSB.dbo.People' )  a on c.ContractID = a.contractid`

Comment: @AaronBertrand, No, but this works WHERE ContractId = ''56762EBA-DB77-4C23-989C-4E03E0C5D7E9''') a,   And If I take the OpenQuery Select and run it in the other server it works also

Comment: The way you originally wrote your query would imply that table Contracts is located at the remote server. But there's neither a database nor a schema to identify where that table can be located. My guess would be that Contracts is a local table. If that's the case then Conrads approach is one way to solve. Alternatively, you could copy the data from the remote table RSB.dbo.People to a local, indexed temp table and query that table. Joins against tables on a remote system may provide bad performance. Needs to be testes case by case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your linked server was likely setup with "master" (or another DB) as the default database and I would guess that the table "Contracts" is not in that database.  Always fully qualify your table with the database and schema when using linked servers, or not.